# Java compilation question regarding casting

Tags: java, object, compiler-construction, casting

If I have two objects not related to each other. What will happen in the following cases:
We have: Object A, Object B

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
```

> 1. a = b;     \will compile? will I get an exception?
> 2. a = (A) b;      \will compile ? afterwards - will I get an exception?

Comment: Just compile it yourself and look at the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply compile them to get the answer as well.

1. **No** Won't compile
2. **No** Won't compile

**See Also**

- [Conversions and Promotions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html)

Answer (score 2):

Both won't compile, in the second case only if the compiler can check the types, so if you first go through Object you would be able to cast and get an exception at runtime

Answer (score 0):

If the two objects are unrelated you will not be able to cast one to the other.
1.  Will not compile.
2.  Will compile, but will throw an exception at runtime.

If one object was inherited from the other, then you would be able to cast the one to the other.